# Error with large data set using openpyxl python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I've got an excel file xlsx (shape:1180,6) that I'm trying to manipulate around. Pretty much creating an empty row every other row and inserting data to it, by just re-arranging the data. The code runs fine when i try it with just 10 rows of data but fails when i run the entire 1180 rows. It also runs a long time before spitting out the same unprocessed data. Is openpyxl not built for this? Just wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing it. Here's my code. Below the code is data after using a few rows, which is what i need, but fails for the entire data set.

```
%%time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os

xls = pd.ExcelFile('input.xlsx')
df = xls.parse(0)
wb = load_workbook('input.xlsx')
#print(wb.sheetnames)
sh1=wb['Sheet1']
df.head()
#print(sh1.max_column)

for y in range(2,(sh1.max_row+1)*2,2):
    sh1.insert_rows(y)
    wb.save('output.xlsx')    
    m=3
for k in range(2,sh1.max_row+1,2):
    sh1.cell(row=k,column=1).value = sh1.cell(row=m,column=1).value # copy from one cell and paste
    sh1.cell(row=k,column=2).value = sh1.cell(row=m,column=3).value
    sh1.cell(row=k,column=3).value = sh1.cell(row=m,column=2).value
    sh1.cell(row=k,column=4).value = 'A'
    sh1.cell(row=m,column=4).value = 'H'
    sh1.cell(row=k,column=5).value = sh1.cell(row=m,column=6).value
    sh1.cell(row=k,column=6).value = sh1.cell(row=m,column=5).value
    m+=2
    wb.save('output.xlsx')

xls = pd.ExcelFile('output.xlsx')
df1 = xls.parse(0)
wb1 = load_workbook('output.xlsx')
df1
```

[image: Data Sample]

Comment: Could you post your entire error message?

Comment: Hi Gilseung, its not really an error msg, but the output file is pretty much the input file when the code runs the entire data set file, (1200 rows xlsx file). Whenever I test it with the short sample, (20 row file) it works fine and produces the output above.